# comments.php remove date/time's #hyperlink

Tags: comments

I can't find a solution to remove the hyperlink from the comments. There is always this hyperlink #comment in every comments I have.

I've tried a lot of things, but the only thing I'm able to do is to hide it via css (but I want to completely remove it).

Though, I've been able to remove all the links from the comments, even the "cancel your reply" one.

But it seems almost impossible to remove the #hyperlink.

Do you think it is possible ? If yes, how to?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it the hyperlink on the date/time?

Comment: This depends on the theme you are using. Its developer should be able to help you.

Comment: @SahriarSaikat Yes it is the hyperlink on the date/time : <span class="time"><a href="#comment-587"> at </a></span> (I removed almost everything, so the only thing that is left is the "at" hyperlink)